# VStudio theme in eclipse?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, eclipse

I am a .net developer working with VStudio from few years. 
Now due to some priority I have to work in java using eclipse studio. I am very fond of vstudio theme and color.. can someone help me to find vstudio theme for eclipse ?

Answer (score 1):

I understand you, but is it really worth placing the VS color themes onto Eclipse and mainly Java (I guess) code??

You'll be accustomed to the new color syntax highlighting of your code in a couple of days. I know what I'm talking about, I'm professionally developing with the .Net framework at work and with Eclipse, Java and Android for my studies at the university. It's just a matter of getting accustomed ;)

What I found more problematic is when you deviate from the standard syntax highlighting. This may really cause confusion, especially if you're doing pair programming sessions with your work mates, since they are not accustomed to your colors. So basically I'd just stick with the standard IDE highlighting and coloring.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Color Theme (http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/) plugin has at least one (if not more) visual studio color scheme.